# Add a new class into the css style with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

how can i insert a new class into the current css?

```
var myStyle = $("head > style:eq(2)");


if( document.styleSheets[2].cssRules ) {
    myStyle.insertRule('#test { display:block; }', 0);
} else {
    if ( document.styleSheets[2].rules ) {
        myStyle.addRule('#test', 'display:block;');
    }
}
```

dd

Comment: You want to do this because you need to actually insert the class, or do you just want to hide object with id=test, as in $("#test").css('display', 'none');

Comment: There is no such thing as "a class" in CSS, nor is there anything (IIRC) that can nest in the language. Do you mean "How can I insert a new rule into an existing rule-set?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be switching between a *styleSheet* object and the result of a framework's selector function (possibly jQuery).  Stick with *document.styleSheets* for the whole thing:

```
var myStyle = document.styleSheets[2];

if( myStyle.cssRules ) {
    myStyle.insertRule('#test { display:block; }', 0);
} else if ( myStyle.rules ) {
    myStyle.addRule('#test', 'display:block;');
}
```

<sub>nb: I did away with the redundant *if* block, switching to an *else if* instead.  You could do away with the *else if* condition and just leave it as *else*, if you wanted.</sub>